# How to avoid redundancy of assets splitting Android app into modules?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am planning to split my app, feature-wise into a set of independent modules. Many of the features (modules in my new design) share the image assets and string constants.

If I add the reusable assets in the main/app module then they would be compiled into the APK even if I don't include the modules using them. If I add the reusable assets to all the modules, then I face all the problems that come with redundancy.

What is the correct approach of splitting app into modules ? End-goal of my design is to enable/disable any feature during the build phase (through build.gradle).

Comment: Create additional modules for the reusable assets. Have the library modules depend upon those asset modules, in whatever combinations are necessary. Gradle will handle the rest.

Comment: Thanks. Please make this comment an answer, and I will accept it once I test the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that we have App A, and Libraries L<sub>1</sub>, L<sub>2</sub>, and L<sub>3</sub>. L<sub>1</sub> and L<sub>2</sub> share some common resources and/or assets. From a production standpoint, only one copy of those common resources and/or assets would be included anyway, but redundancy is bad from the standpoint of development (e.g., ensuring you change both copies).

So, I'd create a Resource Module M<sub>foo</sub> that contains those common resources and/or assets. Have L<sub>1</sub> and L<sub>2</sub> depend upon M<sub>foo</sub>. Have different product flavors(?) of A depend upon various mixes of L<sub>1</sub>, L<sub>2</sub>, and L<sub>3</sub>. Only one copy of M<sub>foo</sub> will be used, as Gradle will net out the transitive dependencies. This is no different than, say, L<sub>1</sub> and L<sub>2</sub> both depending on `support-v13`.

Of course, depending upon how many libraries you have and the mix of shared stuff, you could get into Michael Bay-level combinatorial 'splosions here.